# pasar datos de array a otra página

Tags: php, html

Tengo estas dos páginas:
index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MOTO GP</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#003399">
        <!-- <center> -->
            <hr>
                <img src=motogp.jpg>
                <h1><font color="white">CLASIFICACION</font></h1>
            <hr>
            <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
                <p><font face="Georgia,Times New Roman,Times,serif" size="3" color=white>
                Seleccione el piloto que desea consultar:
                <select name="piloto">
                    <option value="Jorge Lorenzo">Jorge Lorenzo</option>
                    <option value="Marc Marquez">Marc Marquez</option>
                    <option value="Dani Pedrosa">Dani Pedrosa</option>
                    <option value="Valentino Rossi">Valentino Rossi</option>
                    <option value="Alvaro Bautista">Alvaro Bautista</option>
                    <option value="Hector Barbera">Hector Barbera</option>
                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
                </font></p>
            </form>
        <!-- </center> -->
        <?php
            $pilotos=array(
                "Jorge Lorenzo"=>array(
                    "Catar"=>4,
                    "Americas"=>2,
                    "España"=>2,
                    "Francia"=>1,
                    "Italia"=>3,
                    "Cataluña"=>1,
                    "Assen"=>2
                ),
                "Marc Marquez"=>array(
                    "Catar"=>2,
                    "Americas"=>1,
                    "España"=>1,
                    "Francia"=>3,
                    "Italia"=>2,
                    "Cataluña"=>2,
                    "Assen"=>1
                ),
                "Dani Pedrosa"=>array(
                    "Catar"=>3,
                    "Americas"=>3,
                    "España"=>4,
                    "Francia"=>2,
                    "Italia"=>4,
                    "Cataluña"=>4,
                    "Assen"=>4
                ),
                "Valentino Rossi"=>array(
                    "Catar"=>1,
                    "Americas"=>4,
                    "España"=>3,
                    "Francia"=>4,
                    "Italia"=>1,
                    "Cataluña"=>3,
                    "Assen"=>3
                ),
                "Alvaro Bautista"=>array(
                    "Catar"=>7,
                    "Americas"=>5,
                    "España"=>5,
                    "Francia"=>5,
                    "Italia"=>7,
                    "Cataluña"=>6,
                    "Assen"=>6
                ),
                "Hector Barbera"=>array(
                    "Catar"=>6,
                    "Americas"=>7,
                    "España"=>6,
                    "Francia"=>7,
                    "Italia"=>6,
                    "Cataluña"=>5,
                    "Assen"=>7
                ),
            );
            if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
                $piloto=$_POST['piloto'];
                $arr_length=count($piloto);
                for($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++){
                    if($piloto[$i]==$piloto){
                        $long=count($piloto[$i]);
                        for($j=0;$j<$long;$j++){
                            echo $piloto[$i][$j];
                            ?> <input type='hidden' name="$piloto[$i][$j]" value="$j"> <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

resultado.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MOTO GP</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#003399">
        <!-- <center> -->
            <hr>
                <img src=motogp.jpg>
                <h1><font color="white">INFORMACION PILOTO</font></h1>
            <hr>
            <?php
                $piloto=$_POST['piloto'];
            ?>
            <p style="color:white;">La clasificacion de <?php echo $piloto; ?> es:</p>
            <table border=1 style="color:white;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Gran Premio</td><td>Posicion</td><td>Puntos</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php  ?></td><td><?php  ?></td><td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <!-- </center>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Quiero que al seleccionar un piloto y darle al botón buscar, me aparezcan en la otra página una tabla con las carreras de ese piloto con sus puestos y puntuaciones.
No puedo usar variables de sesión ni nada más, solo me han indicado que necesitaría un "require", pero no creo que sirva para eso.

Comment: En efecto, necesitas un `require('index.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente:

Primero separamos el array con todos nuestros registros, de momento para fines practicos lo llamaremos database.php:

**database.php**

```
$db=array(
    "Jorge Lorenzo"=>array(
        "Catar"=>4,
        "Americas"=>2,
        "España"=>2,
        "Francia"=>1,
        "Italia"=>3,
        "Cataluña"=>1,
        "Assen"=>2
    ),
    "Marc Marquez"=>array(
        "Catar"=>2,
        "Americas"=>1,
        "España"=>1,
        "Francia"=>3,
        "Italia"=>2,
        "Cataluña"=>2,
        "Assen"=>1
    ),
    "Dani Pedrosa"=>array(
        "Catar"=>3,
        "Americas"=>3,
        "España"=>4,
        "Francia"=>2,
        "Italia"=>4,
        "Cataluña"=>4,
        "Assen"=>4
    ),
    "Valentino Rossi"=>array(
        "Catar"=>1,
        "Americas"=>4,
        "España"=>3,
        "Francia"=>4,
        "Italia"=>1,
        "Cataluña"=>3,
        "Assen"=>3
    ),
    "Alvaro Bautista"=>array(
        "Catar"=>7,
        "Americas"=>5,
        "España"=>5,
        "Francia"=>5,
        "Italia"=>7,
        "Cataluña"=>6,
        "Assen"=>6
    ),
    "Hector Barbera"=>array(
        "Catar"=>6,
        "Americas"=>7,
        "España"=>6,
        "Francia"=>7,
        "Italia"=>6,
        "Cataluña"=>5,
        "Assen"=>7
    ),
);
```

Ahora importamos nuestra db en nuestro archivo index.php

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MOTO GP</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#003399">
        <!-- <center> -->
            <hr>
                <img src=motogp.jpg>
                <h1><font color="white">CLASIFICACION</font></h1>
            <hr>
            <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
                <p><font face="Georgia,Times New Roman,Times,serif" size="3" color=white>
                Seleccione el piloto que desea consultar:
                <select name="piloto">
                    <option value="Jorge Lorenzo">Jorge Lorenzo</option>
                    <option value="Marc Marquez">Marc Marquez</option>
                    <option value="Dani Pedrosa">Dani Pedrosa</option>
                    <option value="Valentino Rossi">Valentino Rossi</option>
                    <option value="Alvaro Bautista">Alvaro Bautista</option>
                    <option value="Hector Barbera">Hector Barbera</option>
                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
                </font></p>
            </form>
        <!-- </center> -->
        <?php
            require('database.php');
            $pilotos = $db;
            if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
                $piloto=$_POST['piloto'];
                $arr_length=count($pilotos);
                for($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++){
                    if($pilotos[$i]==$piloto){
                        $long=count($pilotos[$i]);
                        for($j=0;$j<$long;$j++){
                            echo $pilotos[$i][$j];
                            ?> <input type='hidden' name="$pilotos[$i][$j]" value="$j"> <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y por último podemos importar nuestra "database" en el archivo resultado.php y hacer con ello lo que necesitemos.

**resultado.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MOTO GP</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#003399">
        <!-- <center> -->
            <hr>
                <img src=motogp.jpg>
                <h1><font color="white">INFORMACION PILOTO</font></h1>
            <hr>
            <?php
                require('database.php');
                $piloto=$_POST['piloto'];
            ?>
            <p style="color:white;">La clasificacion de <?php echo $piloto; ?> es:</p>
            <table border=1 style="color:white;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Gran Premio</td><td>Posicion</td><td>Puntos</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $db[$piloto]["x"]  ?></td>
                    <td><?= $db[$piloto]["y"] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $db[$piloto]["z"] ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <!-- </center>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Jesús, gracias por la respuesta, creo que me funciona, pero me surgen dos dudas: una es que los bucles for del index sobrarían? y la otra: los valores x y z como los cambio para que puedan salir los datos de cada circuito?

Comment: Efectivamente se pueden omitir y en su lugar aplicar algo similar a lo que se aplica en `resultado.php`.  En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, no tengo idea, te puse el ejemplo de `x`, `y` y `x` debido a que no especificas de donde sacar esos valores. Saludos!